# How can I find the location of packages installed by conda, like pip show?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

For example, when I use `pip install numpy`, I can use `pip show numpy` to get the location of numpy package.

When I install numpy by conda, e.g. `conda install numpy`, how can I get the location of this package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to either

1. Open a prompt

   ```
   >>> import numpy
   >>> print(numpy.__file__)
   ```
2. Use a tool that will do that. I wrote "whych" for that purpose.

   ```
   python3 -m whych numpy
   ```

   will show the full path to the python executable that was used. You can also show the package version with

   ```
   python3 -m whych numpy --module-version
   ```

   (this is optional as it requires to actually import the module). The library
   also works within Python (useful in jupyter notebooks for instance):

   ```
   from whych import whych
   whych("numpy")
   ```

As you can guess, I use the second solution. It is really convenient when you work on several computers and sometimes use pip, sometimes conda, and sometimes the package manager.